# Spring form:input timezone settings with LocaleResolver?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, timezone

Trying to figure out how Spring's timezone handling works. Timezone conversion seems to work OK for `<fmt:formatDate>` tags, but fails to work for Spring's own `<form:input>` tags. I have a following simple test JSP:

```
Plain: ${dateTest.date}
Fmt: <fmt:formatDate value="${dateTest.date}" type="both" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long"/>

<form:form action="..." commandName="dateTest">
  Form: <form:input path="date"/>
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

On controller side - very simple controller which just echoes the values received on submission. In configuration - localeResolver is set to a test resolver which always returns `Europe/Moscow` (MSK) as a timezone (local timezone is PST)

When JSP page first displayed the output is as follows:

```
Plain: Fri Nov 07 20:43:51 PST 2014
Fmt: November 8, 2014 8:43:51 MSK AM

Form: [07/11/2014]
```

The timezone conversion seems to be working fine for `<fmt>` output - the timezone is MSK, but the date in the form field is set to "7/11", which is a local timezone date (PST).

On controller side RequestContext.getTimezone() returns correct (MSK) timezone.

There seems to be no conversion for the  tags, but the Spring documentation (16.9.1) states[1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-timezone) that "Time zone information will automatically be used by Date/Time  converter and Formatter objects registered with Spring’s ConversionService."

Has anyone ever encountered that/worked around this issue? How do you normally handle timezone conversion for `<form:input>` tags?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?  Would be interested in hearing how you got on.

Comment: Setting a custom `AbstractLocaleContextResolver` (with `resolveLocaleContext` returning an instance of `TimeZoneAwareLocaleContext`) as a default 'localeResolver' worked for us.

Comment: Additionally, (I don't remember if that was required or not) you may need to register a `CustomDateEditor` in your controllers. That editor's `DateFormat` timezone must be set to the current one. (This may be optional, so just try the localeResolver first)